# Elasticsearch Query parameter with sort keyword

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been using ES 5.4.0 version and created index and documents (student data). when i do search based on age , _search end point is returning value and output is as expected. Did the same for name desc option. i am getting below exception

```
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [name] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "students",
        "node": "MESiRCvSSgqMNWEVwMevMg",
        "reason": {
          "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [name] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."
```

what could be the reason. As per log i have to add fileddata=true. any reason behind this.

http://localhost:9200/students/data/_search?q=montana&sort=age:desc - working fine.

http://localhost:9200/students/data/_search?q=montana&sort=name:desc - not working

http://localhost:9200/students/data/_search?q=montana&sort=name:desc&fielddata=true - added fielddata - not wokring

// http://localhost:9200/students?

```
{
  "students": {
    "aliases": {

    },
    "mappings": {
      "data": {
        "properties": {
          "age": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "city": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "company": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "email": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "gender": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "phone": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "state": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "street": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1530174012103",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "PrtajDL0SwS-tTX7Gm_YQw",
        "version": {
          "created": "5040099"
        },
        "provided_name": "students"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the result you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/students`? (please update your question with the result)

Comment: @Val.. updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot sort on a `text` field (you can but the results wouldn't make sense), however, you can sort on a `keyword` field, so the following query will work:

```
http://localhost:9200/students/data/_search?q=montana&sort=name.keyword:desc
                                                                   ^
                                                                   |
                                                                add this
```

Comment: it is working as expected.. Any reason? why we have to use keyword.

Comment: Yes, a good reason which is explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/fielddata.html)